# Flask_Pymongo: How to find collections?

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

How to find collections using a variable without an if statement?

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["MONGO_URI"] = "mongodb+srv://user:password@dataprofiles-pcdlh.mongodb.net/Profiles?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
mongo = PyMongo(app)

def page(page_id):
    if page_id == 'wellness':
        cards = [card for card in mongo.db.wellness.find()]
    if page_id == 'ratemds':
        cards = [card for card in mongo.db.ratemds.find()]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I undrestand your question, you are trying to reference a MongoDB collection based on a variable name.

pymongo supports this through the following construct:

```
db[<string variable>].find()
```

So your example would be:

```
def page(page_id):
    cards = [card for card in mongo.db[page_id].find()]
```